# Grails: Db row update fails silently when domain class contains 'version false'

Tags: mysql, database, grails, sql-update, version

I'm using grails v3.2.9

I have a domain class `Offer` containing

```
static mapping = {
    version false
}
```

I insert a row to a `offer` table, then in another transaction I try to update a value of one column inside that row, but `offer` update silently fails while other entities in the same transaction are updated properly.

I save the `offer` as follows:

```
offer.save(failOnError: true)
```

so it is not the case of `offer.save()` when the validation fails and saving fails silently.

However if I add `version` column to `offer` table(`dbCreate` is set to `none`) and change the `Offer` domain class to contain

```
static mapping = {
    version true
}
```

the row starts to be updated successfully.

When I inspect the `audit_log` for `offer` table there is only the insertion events, no any `update` event is there.

It is very weird as I have other domain classes containing `version = false` and updating there works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since version = false, the property Offer.version is equal to null and the column does not exist in database. Normally when you perform updates Hibernate will automatically check the version property against the version column in the database. So, I am just guessing it may be a bug with the hibernate session trying check a value that is null. I tried to replicate your scenario but I did not succeed.

Have you tried flushing the session when you save?:

```
offer.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

Comment: Logically when `version` is false , hibernate should not check anything related to version. Didn't try with `flush: true` but event it will succeed I'll not see any explanation of such behavior.

Comment: Could you share more details about your code to be able to replicate the same scenario? It would be useful to track down this issue if you share a project on GitHub  that shows this exact behavior

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that when you changed the domain that required version to a domain that doesn't require version, the underlying database table didn't drop that column.

By default the version column is created as NOT NULL in the physical database. Even though hibernate doesn't care about the version property in the domain, the physical database won't let that record inserted and hence it fails.

While this explains why a record is not inserted, it doesn't explain why it doesn't throw an error. It shouldn't fail silently and instead throw a SQL exception.

Comment: yeah exception is not thrown and other entities in transaction are updated properly. Also my db schema is not generated automatically from domain classes, `dbCreate` is disabled and in db table `version` column was absent when `version` was false in domain class